# How to detect used file monitor in "gio monitor"

Tags: glib, gio

`glib` supports several file monitors. The used monitor can be detected by calling `G_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME (monitor)`.

When using the `gio` program, there is no documented way to determine this. Or is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by several file monitors? There's just GFileMonitor and that's what the gio tool uses when using `gio monitor <location>`

Comment: There are several implementations (backends): GFamFileMonitor, GInotifyFileMonitor, GKqueueFileMonitor and GPollFileMonitor at least. I need to know which implementation is used.

Comment: Oh now I got it: you want the internal implementation. The tool uses the public gio API so it doesn't even know. Are you sure you need to know that?

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm writing regression tests for `gio monitor`, and the fired events differ, depending on the backend.

Comment: So what you probably want is to force a specific monitor implementation... one of the  environment variables like `GIO_USE_FILE_MONITOR=inotify` might help?

Comment: That's a good indication, thanks. However, my test scenarii are more complex. I connect a remote server, and I do run `gio monitor` there for my tests. I don't know what the server is running - it could be GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, macOS, cygwin, Solaris, you name it. That's why I want to have a simple check about the backend gio is using.

Comment: Well, you'll nailed it. `env GIO_USE_FILE_MONITOR=help gio monitor /` returns exactly the information I am looking for.